# What objects should not be spring managed?

Tags: spring

What objects should not be managed by spring containers ? To my understanding, data transfer objects need not be spring managed and can be created with new operator... but is there a generic rule and reasoning which i can follow while developing web applications...

Comment: Any two objects which are dependent each other are eligible to manage by Spring.  DTOs are like method arguments passing between messaging between two objects.  So they dont need to be managed by Spring as they have to be instantiated as part of method invocation.

Comment: Interesting question. We got some wrappers around unmanaged objects. The unmanaged objects are from generated code. These wrappers are also unmanaged.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is all about DI so you take object A mark it with a nice @Component or @Service annotation and then you can inject it it object B. DI is what you gain . You are looking for when not to use DI? DTO's , helper classes in general,whatever not worth making an interface for it ,not worth getting an annotation. Controllers on the other hand, DAOS , services in general worth being Spring managed.